# Need to post JSON from endpoint to Prometheus using node js

Tags: node.js, json, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I need to post JSON to Prometheus by collecting the data from endpoint using Node JS. Kindly give me some samples to work on this.

Comment: You need to show work from your side. What have you tried so far? What is the issue you are facing? Cannot just put whatever your boss/teacher has asked you to do and expect people to do it for you, without any research from your side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot 'post to Prometheus'. Prometheus works in pull mode. It scrapes metrics exposed by services and exporters. The easiest way to do this is in your node.js application is by using an existing client library. Look at the examples here: https://github.com/siimon/prom-client/tree/master/example.

Answer (score 4):

You can "push" data to prometheus using the push gateway:

https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway

This is not recommended because it will not clean up data automatically for you, so you need to have a cron or something periodically delete old data, or your filesystem will eventually fill up.

The way it works is, the pushgateway is a module that you push data to, and then prometheus will pull data from the pushgateway normally. It's kind of a pain to get up and running, but it's nice to have in situations where you can't pull data for whatever reason (i.e., devices on a LAN can only establish outgoing connections, but aren't directly accessible by a prometheus server).